# Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation'

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, xbap

I have deployed my `WPF browser application` that is using `Prism` with `MEF` on `IIS 7`.
But I encounter the following error after the IE finishes downloading the applications files.
Before I forget, I should mention that it works fine in debug mode and also when I browse the xbap file by IE.
I am using `VS2010 sp1` on a `Windows 7 sp1` machine.

Here is the detailed error:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

   at System.AppDomain.nCreateInstance(String friendlyName, AppDomainSetup setup, Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo, IntPtr parentSecurityDescriptor)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstanceHelper(AppDomainSetup adSetup)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Windows.Interop.PresentationApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext actCtx)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.ExecuteNewDomain()
   at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.Execute()
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.ExecuteDownloadedApplication()
   at System.Windows.Interop.DocObjHost.RunApplication(ApplicationRunner runner)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.XappLauncherApp_Exit(Object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoShutdown()
   at System.Windows.Application.ShutdownImpl()
   at System.Windows.Application.ShutdownCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.StartDispatcherInBrowser(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

---

```
PresentationHost.exe v3.0.6920.4902 built by: NetFXw7 - C:\Windows\System32\PresentationHost.exe
ntdll.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
kernel32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
KERNELBASE.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ADVAPI32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
msvcrt.dll v7.0.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
sechost.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
RPCRT4.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
USER32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
GDI32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LPK.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
USP10.dll v1.0626.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
ole32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
OLEAUT32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 - C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
mscoree.dll v4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000) - C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll
SHLWAPI.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
WININET.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
Normaliz.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\Normaliz.dll
urlmon.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
CRYPT32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
MSASN1.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
iertutil.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
SHELL32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
IMM32.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
MSCTF.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
PresentationHost_v0400.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel -C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationHost_v0400.dll
MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll v10.00.30319.1 - C:\Windows\System32\MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll
VERSION.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\VERSION.dll
PSAPI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
CRYPTBASE.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll
uxtheme.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
CBTLaunch.dll v3.7.0.32 - C:\Program Files\Red Gate\SQL Prompt 4\CBTLaunch.dll
CLBCatQ.DLL v2001.12.8530.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
CRYPTSP.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTSP.dll
rsaenh.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
RpcRtRemote.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\RpcRtRemote.dll
dwmapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll
comctl32.dll v6.10 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc\comctl32.dll
SspiCli.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\SspiCli.dll
profapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
ws2_32.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\ws2_32.DLL
NSI.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
dnsapi.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.DLL
iphlpapi.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\iphlpapi.DLL
WINNSI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\WINNSI.DLL
RASAPI32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\RASAPI32.dll
rasman.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\rasman.dll
rtutils.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\rtutils.dll
sensapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\sensapi.dll
peerdist.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\peerdist.dll
USERENV.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\USERENV.dll
AUTHZ.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\AUTHZ.dll


mswsock.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
wshtcpip.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
NLAapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
rasadhlp.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
dfshim.dll v4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000) - C:\Windows\System32\dfshim.dll
mscoreei.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
clr.dll v4.0.30319.225 (RTMGDR.030319-2200) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
wship6.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
fwpuclnt.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
msxml3.dll v8.110.7600.16385 - C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll
ieproxy.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Program Files\InternetExplorer\ieproxy.dll
SXS.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\SXS.DLL
PresentationHostProxy.dll v4.0.31106.0 built by: Main - C:\Windows\System32\PresentationHostProxy.dll
mshtml.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll
msls31.dll v3.10.349.0 - C:\Windows\System32\msls31.dll
mlang.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
msimtf.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\msimtf.dll
IEFRAME.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\IEFRAME.dll
OLEACC.dll v7.0.0.0 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\OLEACC.dll
jscript.dll v5.8.7600.16385 - C:\Windows\System32\jscript.dll
ImgUtil.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\ImgUtil.dll
pngfilt.dll v8.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\pngfilt.dll
mscorlib.ni.dll v4.0.30319.225 (RTMGDR.030319-2200) - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\eb4e1e70734f6efb9c7de7ec5f452c9e\mscorlib.ni.dll
nlssorting.dll v4.0.30319.225 (RTMGDR.030319-2200) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
System.ni.dll v4.0.30319.225 built by: RTMGDR - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\4d67e7b436c61b8141d19f99f7d2c75e\System.ni.dll
WindowsBase.ni.dll v4.0.30319.225 built by: RTMGDR - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\bde920dbf9e20e926b60106042e16d64\WindowsBase.ni.dll
PresentationCore.ni.dll v4.0.30319.225 built by: RTMGDR - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\887688af9665ecb951b418d5982a3c5d\PresentationCore.ni.dll
PresentationFramework.ni.dll v4.0.30319.225 - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationFramewo#\5f8ab715f37b56cc76c8a130dbc6e74b\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
dwrite.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\dwrite.dll
wpfgfx_v0400.dll v4.0.30319.225 built by: RTMGDR - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
PresentationNative_v0400.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationNative_v0400.dll
msimg32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
System.Xaml.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml\0c8167f224c2ac6fdba796bd53cdd338\System.Xaml.ni.dll
System.Deployment.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Deployment\f2aa6fd240cb912568c2b6811b101726\System.Deployment.ni.dll
shfolder.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\shfolder.dll
System.Configuration.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\9ea5f775ad6b7af3e326a08e26ff06a3\System.Configuration.ni.dll
System.Xml.ni.dll v4.0.30319.225 built by: RTMGDR - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\c27f2137e0e6185d243251544f9ec0c9\System.Xml.ni.dll
winhttp.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\winhttp.dll
webio.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\webio.dll
credssp.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\credssp.dll
dhcpcsvc6.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
dhcpcsvc.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
System.Security.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100) - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Security\31b164d1230fb8b86e10858ba96e6cd5\System.Security.ni.dll
cryptnet.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\cryptnet.dll
WLDAP32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
dsrole.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\dsrole.dll
clrjit.dll v4.0.30319.225 (RTMGDR.030319-2200) - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
System.Drawing.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\c751ad524dc3ec593de1883b9f0ad0ae\System.Drawing.ni.dll
System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll v4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\d43f6750bf5e42fd2183991957147df1\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
GPAPI.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\GPAPI.dll
Cabinet.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\Cabinet.dll
DEVRTL.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\DEVRTL.dll
ncrypt.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll
bcrypt.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
bcryptprimitives.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll
gdiplus.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7600.16385_none_72fc7cbf861225ca\gdiplus.dll
WindowsCodecs.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.dll
System.Core.ni.dll v4.0.30319.225 built by: RTMGDR - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\58cbae39cc6370050c776b0ffeffcab3\System.Core.ni.dll
diasymreader.dll v10.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add the assembly for this interface to your deployed assemblies? Prism is not part of the .NET framework, so it needs to be installed / deployed with your application.

Comment: I had included all prism related assemblies before publishing.

Comment: I have not provided the list of included assemblies, that's the error detail provided by IE. The list of assemblies included for deployment can be seen in the Publish section of the project properties in visual studio. There I included all dependencies and furthermore I checked them out in deployment path, and all of them were present there. and all of the required assemblies are being copied into the client's folder when I access the IIS deplyed XBAP using IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll file from https://servicelocation.codeplex.com/